# menu cannot be resolved or is not a field - in the R.java

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I have seen many post with a similar issue.

My R.java file has been generated but it's missing the elements below

1. Project clean does nothing
2. There's no errors in my res folder

It cannot be resolved for the areas e.g. menu, action.edit, action.delete, action.new

Example 1:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
public  boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_edit: {
                if (mEditMode) {
                    sendPutRequest(new PutResponseListener());
                }
                setEditMode(!mEditMode);

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return false;
            }
            case R.id.action_delete: {
                sendDeleteRequest(new DeleteResponseListener());
                return false;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: `import yourpkg.R;` in your activity and also `import android.view.Menu;`

Comment: They have been imported already.

Comment: then you might go wrong some where else.

Comment: Do your other references to `R` work fine? If so, can you post your menu XML?

Comment: Yes everything other than menu, action.edit... etc. (listed above)

Comment: Fixed it. I don't know how but it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the 
`import android.R` somewhere in your java file. Change that to import `com.yourpackage.R`.

Comment: Yes they have been imported previously.

Answer (score 0):

should be user Operate process question.
rebuild your project/res/menu/*.xml (your program)

In eclipse window Package Explorer right-click on your project New->Android XML Files

Select elapse Resource Type as project, Enter files name

Click Finish to rebuild code.